# Fields of intermediate cardinality

Tags: field-theory, set-theory, real-numbers

Assuming the existence of a cardinal $\aleph_0 <\mathfrak{m} < 2^{\aleph_0}$, does it follow that there is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: The last time I thought about such issues, I somehow arrived at the conclusion that the existence of *m* is dependent upon or equivalent to the existence of sets of fractional cardinality.

Comment: @Lucian the existence of such an $\mathfrak{m}$ is just dependent on whether CH is true or not, which is independent of ZFC. What are fractional cardinalities? Never heard of those.

Comment: @ Lucian I am also very curious…

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The existence of an infinite cardinality between two consecutive infinite cardinalities $\big(\aleph$ and $2^\aleph\big)$ is the same as the existence of a finite cardinality between two consecutive finite cardinalities $($e.g., like a set with one-and-a-half elemets$)$. So, just like with complex numbers, it's not a question of true or false, but rather a question of *do we allow such sets it to exist, and if so, then what is their usefulness*?

Comment: What in the world is "a set with one-and-a-half elements" and how does the existence of such a set follow from the existence of cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$? (Which by the way are not necessarily consecutive if one does not assume CH.)

Comment: @Lucian I think you misunderstand what's going on with $\aleph_0$ vs. $2^{\aleph_0}$. These are *not* consecutive cardinalities, necessarily - it is consistent with ZFC that there is a set of real numbers with cardinality strictly between them. This has nothing to do with sets with one-and-a-half elements (?).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: The consecutive-ness of ordinals $\aleph$ and $2^\aleph$ is a matter of convention, just like the consecutive-ness of ordinals $1$ and $2$. Conventions can be neither proven nor disproven, only accepted or rejected. The ZFC basically builds a universe whose axiomatic convention is that finite cardinalities are expressed by natural numbers. Does this ultimately imply the continuum hypothesis ? Neither, nor, for the same reason that Euclid's first four postulates are unrelated to the fifth, and we have various geometries.

Comment: @Lucian: No, it is not a matter of convention. You can talk about $\beth$ numbers which are defined using power sets. But it is possible that there are cardinals which are not $\beth$ numbers. What are you going to do then, ignore them? The sets are still there. If $\beth_1=\aleph_2$, you can't ignore the fact there will be a set of reals of size $\aleph_1$ which is then going to be strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It is “possible” for these infinite sets of intermediate cardinality to “exist” in the same manner in which it is also “possible” for the above-mentioned finite sets of intermediate cardinality to also “exist”, or for non-Euclidean geometries also to “exist”. Since I “ignore” the latter two, it would be politically incorrect of me to *not* do the same for the former. The “reals” of *one* ZFC universe $($such as the one we are accustomed to$)$ are not *quite* the same as the reals of *another* ZFC universe $($an extension or modification of the former$)$.

Comment: @Lucian: So your solution for "what sort of cardinalities are intermediate between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$?" is "Let's never mention sets of these cardinalities again!"? That doesn't make much mathematical sense. But you have fun!

Comment: @ Lucian This is Mathematics, not Politics. Mathematical objects do not care about what is politically incorrect and what is not. Neither do I. And there is an enormous difference between cardinals between one and two, and cardinals between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, for two reasons: first the existence of cardinals between the latter is consistent with ZFC, while the existence of cardinals between the former is not;

Comment: second, and most importantly, while I currently have no picture of what a set of intermediate cardinality would look like, I do have a picture of the aleph sequence of cardinals, and I can imagine that a proposition of the form $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\alpha$ could be true, for some $\alpha \neq 1$. On the other hand, I haven't the faintest idea of what a "set with  two and a half elements" could possibly be. Perhaps you have some picture of that, but I have none, and I cannot imagine the existence of such a set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My solution would be to construct an extension of the current ZFC, which axiomatically accepts the consecutive-ness of $\beth$ numbers for infinite sets in the same manner in which it also accepts the consecutive-ness of natural numbers for finite sets. And, afterwards, to inspect the question of possible future extensions to encompass sets of intermediate cardinality. After all, we are able to speak of fractional-order derivatives, matrix exponentiation, extend factorials and binomial coefficients to $\Gamma$ and beta functions, etc.

Comment: @Daniel: That's because the ZFC was created by human beings, for which the non-fractional cardinality of finite sets is intuitively obvious, which is why this concept has been embedded into the system from its inception on the level of axioms. But the latter enjoys no such special down-to-earth crystal-clearness, which is why those same human beings now struggle to wrap their minds around its non-finitary equivalent.

Comment: @Lucian: So you essentially say that we should work in $\sf ZFC+GCH$. That's fine, but that's not the accepted norm. And you can't ignore the fact that other people may disagree with this philosophical outlook, and mathematically there is no reason to accept one over the other. There are good arguments against $\sf GCH$, for example a myriad of forcing axioms which are very natural, or other type of very natural axioms which are generally incompatible with the continuum hypothesis. So until we all decide "more or less" collectively to accept $\sf GCH$ or not, you can't quite insist on that.

Comment: @Lucian Until I have been presented with some explanation of what a "set with fractional cardinality" is or how they behave, I shall consider such sets to be non-entities.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: By *"more or less" collectively* you mean [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) mathematicians ? ;-$)$

Comment: @Daniel: To me, it would seem somehow illogical to tackle the question of sets of **infinite** intermediate cardinality *before* giving even a single thought to sets of **finite** intermediate cardinality. It is as if one were to plunge directly into the abyss before first learning how to even swim in a pool.

Comment: By "more or less" collectively, it is meant that, before GCH be accepted as an axiom of Set Theory, the set of all mathematicians that reject it should have cardinal measure $0$, in other words it must be a set with a fractional cardinal less than $1$ (or should it be less than $n$ for every finite cardinal $n$?); soon enough, we'll have infinitesimal cardinals as well…

Comment: @Lucian But you fail to understand that those are completely different concepts: there is no such a thing as a set with "two and a half elements". But there may very well be a family of subsets of a set, which is not in a bijective correspondence with the set itself nor with the set of all its subsets. That is what is meant by "intermediate cardinality" and not some hallucinatory concept of a "fractional cardinal" that would be between two consecutive cardinals, which is *by definition* impossible (since then they would not be consecutive after all).

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I understand full well what the two notions of countable and uncountable mean, and that not all uncountable sets have the same cardinality. My point, however, was that the GCH might be just as axiomatic, and therefore impossible to prove, as the fact that finite sets have an integer number of elements, for instance. In my opinion, there seems to be an intuitive connection or analogy between the two concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. You can adjoint the subset of cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

First by axiom of choice, you can enumerate the subset of cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$, say $x_0, x_1, ..., x_\mathfrak{m}$. Then construct the tower of extension $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(x_0) \rightarrow \cdots$. Let me write $F_\alpha = \mathbb(x_\gamma | \gamma < \alpha)$. It can be shown that for any ordinal $\alpha$, $|F_\alpha| \leq \aleph_0 |\alpha|$ by transfinite induction. Hence, the eventual field is of cardinality $\leq \aleph_0 \mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: And why is this not bigger than $\mathfrak{m}$, if you generate the field?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma For any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, the closure of a set of size $\kappa$ under a collection of $\kappa$ or fewer finitary functions is of size $\kappa$. This is a straightforward induction.

Comment: I know, but I wanted that argument to be explicit, which you did, +1

Answer (score 1):

A standard theorem on finitary algebraic structures says that if $A$ is an infinite subset of size $\kappa$ of such a structure, the minimal substructure that contains $A$ also has size $\kappa$ (one can deduce this from Löwenheim-Skolem, or use standard set theory closure techniques).

So take any subset $A$ of size $\mathfrak{m}$, and take the minimal field containing $A$. This fits the bill (we automatically get $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield of course).